# Is the smooth mapping space a deformation-retract of the continuous one?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, smooth-manifolds, function-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be smooth manifolds.

Let $F \subset G$ denote the spaces of, respectively, smooth and continuous functions $X\rightarrow Y$; we give $F,G$ the compact-open topologies. (This should be compatible with the subspace topology on $F$ from $G$.)

Since every continuous map is homotopic to a smooth one by e.g. Whitney approxiomation,
we know that $F$ meets every path-component of $G$.

I was wondering, is $F$ furthermore a deformation-retract of $G$?

Comment: The more natural question seems to me whether the inclusion is a (weak) homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For example if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ then the space of all smooth functions (even polynomials) is dense in $C(X,Y)$. And so it cannot be a retract of $C(X,Y)$. This idea generalizes to any smooth manifolds of positive dimension (in dimension $0$ smooth and continuous coincide).

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't considered the issue of density.